# how to update a document in firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a chatroom for my webapp(is an app for house owners to manage their properties) so each property will have a chat room, the structure it is something like:

```
 collection/document/{ChatGroup: messages:{id_message:number, message:string}, users:{id_user: number, username:string}}
```

I am trying to do this:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("properties").where("chatGroup.id_property", "==", 16)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            doc.update(message :message})
        });
   })
```

but I keep getting the message that update is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

firestore documents can be updated with reference. try this if it works for you.

```
firestore.collection("properties")
.doc("YourDocId")
.update({});// Pass your object to write.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are iterating document snapshots, you can find the reference for that document using its [ref](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#ref) property, and use that to perform the update:

```
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        const ref = doc.ref;
        ref.update({message : message})
    });
```